# Can I add wiring directly to the heating element and fan without frying anything?

Tags: heat

I have an LED fireplace that I'm putting in to replace a wall heater.  I wired it to run through the wall thermostat, but when the thermostat turns the fireplace on it just turns on the lights, then you have to manually turn on the heat.
Since I'm already messing with the wiring I'm trying to figure out a way to have the thermostat just turn on one of the heating elements and the fan (so the lights aren't turning on and off every time the thermostat turns on), then also wiring the fireplace through it's main switch so you can manually turn it on anytime with the heat and fan included.
I've included a picture of the wiring diagram, I drew in the secondary wiring for the wall thermostat. My first question is, the heating element and fan-motor are both supplied 120v, so if I wire my 120v line directly to them they shouldn't burn out without a resistor, right?
Second question, if the thermostat and manual switch are ever both tuned on, it shouldn't add any amperage to the heater and fan since they're both coming from the same source wires, right?
Third question, do you see any risk of frying anything else on the boards if I connect the wiring this way?
Thanks in advance for the help!
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are three rectangles on the lower right side of the board, from which there are lines to your heating elements and fan. Do you know if these rectangles represent relays? Do you have a schematic for your board?

Comment: I don't have a schematic for the board but have access to the board. They are relays, I added a picture of them to the original post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about hot-wiring an appliance.

Comment: In particular, it's about hot-wiring an electric _heating_ appliance, for which modifications from its UL listing could cause a fire, and burn down the OPs house. While it may not be explicitly stated, our intent is to provide code-compliant answers, and modifying things from their UL listings isn't code-compliant. We'd hate to be responsible for a house fire...

Comment: Thenut  Greg brought up some good reasons not to do this with a thermostat (it would have to be line voltage rated at the current the heater draws or better). You have a heater with line voltage what kind of wiring or wiring method to use to get the thermostat to work. Romex or NMB in this case may not be legal,  fixture wire (high temp wire) would need to be in conduit, and now the fact that this may bypass the safety’s are all reasons to rethink how you really want to do this. Can it be done probably, what chip is on the board ? Atmega 128 or 328 simple programming update could do it.

Comment: Ed, thanks, Greg did bring up some good points that I am considering. I am looking into possibly reprogramming the chip but that's a big black hole for me. The thermostat itself isn't a concern at all, it's specifically for resistance heaters rated at 120/240VAC, maximum 8.3 A resistive load, max 1000W @120V (which is why I only want to wire it to one of the heating elements, they're 750W each). Why would Romex not be safe? Idaho code requires Romex in the wall, the manual for the heater specifies Romex for direct wiring, and I've only ever seen Romex used for wiring resistance heaters.

Comment: Ed, also both circuits still use the PTC safety switch, which as far as I can tell is the only safety switch built into the unit, so I'm not actually bypassing any safeties. And I fully understand everyone's concern with the safety of this, that's why I'm on here making sure I have all my bases covered before I even consider attempting it. Also, I would be able to wire it up and test it thoroughly before it ever goes into a wall.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fair to give a straight answer to the questions.. and then to follow up with "but don't do it that way."

1. Yes, if the heating element and fan are both mains-powered through the relays, then mains-powering them through an alternate method would cause them to heat/spin just the same.
2. If the relays and some bypass switch were both enabled at the same time there would not be any change to the operation of the heater and fan; they'll continue to pull whatever current they require.
3. Bypassing the relays as you've shown seems unlikely to damage the circuit board.. but it's not a great idea.

We can see the circuit board has some processing logic and a temperature sensor. It may well have some safety logic that looks for stuck relays (relays do get their contacts welded together sometimes) and your bypass approach could unintentionally trigger such logic. There's a temperature limit control shown on the diagram, but if you hot-wire the heating element as proposed, you'll be depending solely on that limit element to protect against over-heating. There must be a better way.

It strikes me as amusing that Electrical Engineering would send the question here -- I'd have guessed electronics maker-themed questions like this would be a nice fit there! (But I'm not an active participant there, so what would I know about that?)

I think you'll do much better to figure out how to give inputs to the fireplace so that its built-in controls do what you want. Find a way to simulate presses on that keyboard, for example. Or acquire the "PCB Remote Controller" accessory the schematic implies might exist, and then figure out how to hack that module for your purposes.

I'm not necessarily averse to overriding or even replacing the control board in the fireplace, but if one is going to pursue that path, there should be attention paid to making it operate safely in the face of various failures. A mechanical switch that turns on the heating element and hopes for the best isn't great. What if the fan motor quits, for example..? The thermostat on the wall won't protect against this fault.

Comment: FYI, these "I want to modify this commercial device but I have no real technical details" questions are typically flagged as off-topic over at the EE stack.

Comment: Thanks for the response and candidness. As lacking as I am in electrical engineering it pales in comparison to how little I know about circuit boards. I wouldn't even know where to begin with modifying the inputs to the board. And yeah I think the guy that sent it over here only read the first line. I see what you're saying with the risk of overheating if the fan fails, but with the PTC switch in-line for both circuits it would prevent that. Yes redundancy would be great, but I highly doubt the system uses more than that switch for safety.

Comment: brhans I have plenty of technical details and believe I gave enough between the description and schematic to be able to answer the questions I asked, with the possible exception of the board safety question. If you're missing something and need more specific information I'd be happy to give it to you. And I actually got some decent answers on the EE stack and it's still standing there.